# Reading variable name from txt file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read variable name from txt file in bash script.

For example

I run `var="thanks"` in terminal
I create file.txt and txt file contains `$var`
I create variable `var2` in terminal. `var2=""`
Then I run `var2=$(<file.txt)` command in terminal.

The Problem is

```
$ echo $var2
"$var"
```

I want the output of the `echo $var` command to be "thanks"

```
$ echo $var2
"thanks"
```

So what should I do?

Comment: There is sourcing for that. Create file with `var2="thanks"` and source it like this `source path_to_file/file` or `. path_to_file/file`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is it you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: I am working with json api's. And I want to write data to json file according to the incoming data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put just `var` into the file without the `$` and quotes, you can use variable indirection.

```
var2=$(< file.txt)
var2=${!var2}
echo $var2
```

Or, if you need the dollar sign and quotes, remove them using parameter expansion before applying the indirection

```
var2=$(< file.txt)
var2=${var2#'"$'}
var2=${var2%\"}
var2=${!var2}
echo $var2
```

Comment: As an alternative to *indirection*, you could use *name reference*, see `declare -n` (and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030688/1765658);)

Answer (score 1):

## Two different bash way for this:

### 1. Using `${!var}` *indirect expansion*:

Anoter way for dropping `$"` if present:

```
IFS='$"' read -a var2 <file.txt
var2=(${var2[*]})
echo ${!var2}
```

Tests:

```
var=Hello\ world\!
echo '"$var"' >file.txt
cat file.txt 
"$var"

IFS='$"' read -a var2 <file.txt
var2=(${var2[*]})
echo ${!var2}
Hello world!

echo 'var' >file.txt 
cat file.txt 
var

IFS='$"' read -a var2 <file.txt
var2=(${var2[*]})
echo ${!var2}
Hello world!
```

#### Explanation:

- `IFS` *Input Field Separator* (usually contain: `$' \t\n'` *`<space><tab><newline>`*). All characters in this field are treated as *field separator*, so don't appear in *array*.
- `IFS='..' read ..` when *variable definition* prepend  *command*, *variable* are only affected for this execution
- `-a var2` read make `var2` an array. Use `declare -p` to show his content:

  ```
   IFS='$"' read -a var2 <file.txt
   declare -p var2
   declare -a var2=([0]="" [1]="" [2]="var")
  ```
- `${var2[*]}` will merge `var`'s fields in a single string, separated by 1st `$IFS` character.

  ```
   echo "<${var2[*]}>"
   <  var>
  ```
- `var2=(  foo bar baz  )` will redefine `var2` ignoring spaces (as any characters in `$IFS`)

  ```
   var2=(${var2[*]})  # This step become useless, in 2nd case, but harmless.
   declare -p var2
   declare -a var2=([0]="var")
  ```
- `${!var2}` is known as *indirect expansion*

  ```
   echo ${!var2}
   Hello world!
  ```

### 2. Using reference name: *nameref*

- `declare -n name=value` make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value

```
IFS='$"' read -a var2 < file.txt
var2=(${var2[*]})
declare -p var2
declare -a var2=([0]="var")

declare -n var3=$var2
echo $var3
Hello world!
```

### This is usefull as `local -n` in a function:

```
readFrom() {
    local var2
    IFS='$"' read -a var2 < $1
    var2=(${var2[*]})
    local -n target=$var2
    echo $target
}
```

Then

```
echo '"$var"' >file.txt
var=Hello\ world\!
readFrom file.txt 
Hello world!
```

#### Alternative to avoid forks when populating variables:

```
readFrom() {
    local var2
    IFS='$"' read -a var2 < $1
    var2=(${var2[*]})
    local -n target=$var2 result=${2:-INPUT}
    result=("$target")
}
```

Then

```
readFrom file.txt newvar
echo "$newvar"
Hello world!
```

Advantage of this:

- you could populate any kind of variables like array of associative arrays
- you could populate many variables in same function

Comment: @ofbahar If you find this answer useful, please upvote (and/or accerpt;-) instead of comment!!